# Merge two classes in one class

Tags: ios, swift, class

I have two classes: 1. Fraction class: numerator and denominator AND  2. OperationWithFractions class which performs a calculation like adding two fractions and represents the result as a String fraction (for example 32 / 5).

It works, but I would like to simplify by merging both classes in only one, so all properties, methods and initializers would be under the same umbrella.

```
class Fraction {
    var numerator = 0
    var denominator = 0

    init (_ numer: Int, _ denom: Int){
        self.numerator = numer
        self.denominator = denom
    }
}

class OperationWithFractions {
    var fraction1: Fraction
    var fraction2: Fraction

    init(_ fraction1: Fraction, _ fraction2: Fraction) {
        self.fraction1 = fraction1
        self.fraction2 = fraction2
    }

    func addFractions()->String {
        var result = ""

        result = "\(fraction1.numerator * fraction2.denominator + fraction1.denominator * fraction2.numerator) / \(fraction1.denominator * fraction2.denominator)"

        return result
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let result = OperationWithFractions(Fraction(5, 10), Fraction(10, 20)).addFractions()
        print(result)

        let result2 = OperationWithFractions(Fraction(10, 2), Fraction(8, 2)).addFractions()
        print(result2)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are these two classes inside the view controller class? Helpful standalone classes should not be put inside one specific view controller.

Comment: Why does `addFractions()` return a string and not a `Fraction` ?

Comment: Thanks maddy, I already changed it

Comment: Martin, that is the challenge: all fractions be represented as "X / Y" Strings, not doubles, etc

Answer (score 3):

Addition of two fractions should return a `Fraction`, not a string. The conversion
to strings is only done if you need a textual representation (e.g. for printing the final result).

Arithmetic operations can be implemented as *operators* of the
fraction type:

```
struct Fraction {
    // ...

    static func +(lhs: Fraction, rhs: Fraction) -> Fraction { ... }
}
```

That allows you to write

```
let result = Fraction(1, 2) + Fraction(-1, 6)
```

Also prefer values types over reference types, and constant properties 
over variable properties. A first implementation could be

```
struct Fraction {
    let numerator: Int
    let denominator: Int

    init (_ numer: Int, _ denom: Int) {
        self.numerator = numer
        self.denominator = denom
    }

    static func +(lhs: Fraction, rhs: Fraction) -> Fraction {
        return Fraction(lhs.numerator * rhs.denominator + lhs.denominator * rhs.numerator,
                        lhs.denominator * rhs.denominator)
    }
}
```

The `CustomStringConvertible` protocol is adopted to provide
the textual representation:

```
extension Fraction: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return "\(numerator)/\(denominator)"
    }
}
```

This already works

```
// Compute 1/2 - 1/6 + 1/3:
let result = Fraction(1, 2) + Fraction(-1, 6) + Fraction(1, 3)
print(result) // 24/36
```

but the result is not completely satisfying because it is
not reduced to the lowest common terms. Also

```
 print(Fraction(2, -3)) // 2/-3
```

is not optimal.

Here is a slightly more sophisticated version where the
results are reduced  to the lowest terms. Apart from the
`gcd` utility function, everything is defined inside the
`Fraction` type.

```
// Greatest common divisor
func gcd(_ a : Int, _ b : Int) -> Int {
    var (a, b) = (a, b)
    while b != 0 {
        (a, b) = (b, a % b)
    }
    return a
}

struct Fraction {
    let numerator: Int
    let denominator: Int

    init (_ numer: Int, _ denom: Int, reduce: Bool = false) {
        if reduce {
            let commonFactor = gcd(numer, denom)
            self.numerator = numer / commonFactor
            self.denominator = denom / commonFactor
        } else {
            self.numerator = numer
            self.denominator = denom
        }
    }

    static func +(lhs: Fraction, rhs: Fraction) -> Fraction {
        return Fraction(lhs.numerator * rhs.denominator + lhs.denominator * rhs.numerator,
                        lhs.denominator * rhs.denominator, reduce: true)
    }
}

extension Fraction: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        if denominator == 1 {
            return "\(numerator)"
        } else if denominator < 0 {
            return "\(-numerator)/\(-denominator)"
        } else {
            return "\(numerator)/\(denominator)"
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
// Compute 1/2 - 1/6 + 1/3:
let result = Fraction(1, 2) + Fraction(-1, 6) + Fraction(1, 3)
print(result) // 2/3
```

Now you can add other operators (e.g. `-`, `*`, `/`), error checking
(e.g. for a zero denominator, or integer overflow), additional instance methods (e.g. “absolut value”), etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
class OperationWithFractions {
    typealias Fraction = (numerator: Int, denominator: Int)

    private let fraction1: Fraction
    private let fraction2: Fraction

    init(_ fraction1: Fraction, _ fraction2: Fraction) {
        self.fraction1 = fraction1
        self.fraction2 = fraction2
    }

    func addFractions() -> String {
        return "\(fraction1.numerator * fraction2.denominator + fraction1.denominator * fraction2.numerator) / \(fraction1.denominator * fraction2.denominator)"
    }
}

let fraction1 = OperationWithFractions.Fraction(numerator: 1, denominator: 2)
let fraction2 = OperationWithFractions.Fraction(numerator: 2, denominator: 3)

let operation = OperationWithFractions(fraction1, fraction2)
print(operation.addFractions()) // 7/6
```

Now, what is going on here?

I converted your entire fraction class into a `typealias` since it exists solely to format your incoming data.

Next, I replaced your `var fraction1: Fraction` with `private let fraction1: Fraction`. This encapsulates logic that only your class needs.

The init function is unchanged.

Finally, I cleaned up your return since there is no need for the initial variable being set and a separate return.

It is also possible to just create an initializer that accepts num1, den1, num2, den2, etc... but this will not scale well should you want to add 3 or more fractions.

Comment: It is good, but can the typealias be changed for a property inside the class, in any way?

Comment: Could you please elaborate about what you would want inside the class? Are you asking if the typealias could be removed and instead something that exists within the class serves the purpose?

Comment: What I want is to be able to pack everytining inside a class name so I can take it copy and paste to other projects, portability..

Comment: @FaustoCheca Ok, I just moved the typealias inside the class and included an example of it in use.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to avoid defining the two properties and initializer in both classes. That's easy enough; just use generics, like

```
class MathematicalOperation<T> {  // you can limit T to numerics, but there's no advantage here
    var firstOperand: T
    var secondOperand: T

    init (_ first: T, _ second: T){
        firstOperand = first
        secondOperand = second
    }
}
```

Then you can subclass this to make your `Fraction` and `OperationWithFractions` subclasses:

```
class Fraction: MathematicalOperation<Int> {
    // no need to define another initializer or properties
}

class OperationWithFractions: MathematicalOperation<Fraction> {
    func addFractions()->String {
        return "\(firstOperand.firstOperand * secondOperand.secondOperand + firstOperand.secondOperand * secondOperand.firstOperand) / \(firstOperand.secondOperand * secondOperand.secondOperand)"
    }
}
```

However, this is obviously less than ideal because `firstOperand.firstOperand`, `secondOperand.firstOperand`, etc. aren't very clear. *And therein lies your problem:* you're trying to save yourself some writing, but in the process, you've muddled the problem you're solving because you've had to pick a generic-enough name for the properties. In that case, it hardly seems worth doing this. You'd have been better off the way you were before, where the property names *meant* something.

Comment: So now instead of reducing the two classes to one (perfectly sensible idea) we have increased it to three separate classes?

Comment: If you like, you can declare your `Int` version without defining a class for it, i.e. `let fraction = MathematicalOperation<Int>(first: 9, second: 6)`, and extend the second one to add the `addFractions()` function, but I suspect that you know this, and OP may not, so in that case, three classes that are easily understood are far better than one or two terse ones that aren’t so easily understood.

Comment: Possibly but I would suggest reducing it down to one fraction class and then implementing the add function to that or even better use operator overloading would be even simpler and easier to understand.  It also avoids the use of generics at all which can be difficult to understand particularly for a beginner and fits the original brief of reducing the classes.  However as you say nothing particularly wrong with this solution in itself.

Comment: I don't think that overloading an operator is conceptually easier for an inexperienced developer to understand than generics, but that's just me.

Comment: Fair point but I also said you can implement the add function in the fraction class which keeps it nice and simple.  There are often multiple solutions to problems some of which have no immediate benefits over each other.  The only reason I even commented it was I was just interested why you chose that idea.

Comment: I chose that idea *entirely* based on *ease of understanding* for new-ish developers, even if that means more code (although even with 3 classes, it's still a lot shorter than OP's original code). I can't think of anything that would make me feel like a failure as a senior developer than writing something that the next person who has to work with it can't understand. That's also why my source files usually contain more comment lines than code.

Comment: Yep fair enough although shorter doesn't always equal easier to understand.  I fully agree about the use of comments though